# Play raw video frame by frame

Tags: c++, video, directx, render

I have a camera which delivers raw frames in a callback function to me. I successfully can store frames and play it using RawVideoPlayer.

Now I want to develop my own player using DirectX. How can I play a video in a window; by setting frame by frame images?

I need a tutorial or help on this. Suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: 1st you need to decode the frames from the video stream to images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look to Windows Media Foundation apis. They provide a clean way to render video to a D3D texture that you can put on any model (typically a quad) in your scene. MF playback api should provide what you need to seek frame by frame in your video.